# How to redirect dynamic changing log to userform textbox with VBA?

Tags: vba, windows-10

I'm using VBA to call a shell cmd(WinSCP.com) and I want to output the processing information of the cmd to a textbox in a userform I designed.

My idea is that the shell cmd will generate a log file during running process, and I just need to output the log file's contents to the textbox.

The problem is, the log is changing when the shell cmd is running, and I don't want to output the log contents as a whole after the cmd finished.

So, my question is :
**Is there a simple way to dynamic monitor the log file contents changing and output the new lines to a textbox during the cmd is running(something like the linux tail -f command)**, or should I just constantly check the log contents to figure out which lines are new and add them to the textbox by myself?

I've Googled a long time and didn't find a solution.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: A "simple way"?  Depends on your definition of "simple" and your comfort level with VBA.  Instead of accessing the file directly, why not programmatically make a copy (which take microseconds) and refer to the copy, so you don't have to worry about conflicts?

Comment: ...or, you could rename the existing log file each time you read it, and then the process should be forced to create a new file. It's not like the process will need to read the file after it's written; most log files are **intended** to be deleted from time to time. Not sure if [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Use_Log_Files_from_VBA) is helpful.

Comment: You can monitor file size. Whenever it grows, you know that and how much was appended to file.

Comment: ashleedawg  &  LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Thank you for your reply！I think rename the log is a good idea! I will give that a try~